# How do i add "lives" in my game using P5.JS?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me with the game that I am creating on P5.JS? I am trying to create lives as a feature on this game however whenever I die in a canyon it takes all lives and does not take just one life and reset the game as it should. Any advice would be really helpful.

```
var gameChar_x;
var gameChar_y;
var floorPos_y;
var scrollPos;
var gameChar_world_x;

var isLeft;
var isRight;
var isFalling;
var isPlummeting;

var trees_x;
var clouds;
var mountains;
var collectables;
var canyon;

var game_score;
var flagpole;
var lives;

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(1024, 576);
    floorPos_y = height * 3/4;
    lives = 3;
    startGame();

}

function draw()
{
    background(100, 155, 255); // fill the sky blue

    noStroke();
    fill(0,155,0);
    rect(0, floorPos_y, width, height/4); // draw some green ground

    push();
    translate(scrollPos, 0);
    drawClouds();
    drawMountains();
    drawTrees();

    for(var i = 0; i < canyon.length; i++)
        {
            drawCanyon(canyon[i]);
            checkCanyon(canyon[i]);
        }
    // Draw collectable items.
    strokeWeight(1)
    for(var i = 0; i < collectables.length; i++)
        {
            if(!collectables[i].isFound)
                {
                    drawCollectable(collectables[i]);
                    checkCollectable(collectables[i]);
                }
        }

    renderFlagpole();

    checkPlayerDie();

    pop();

    // Draw game character.

    drawGameChar();

    fill(255, 0, 0);
    textSize(24);
    text("Lives: " + lives, width/8, 20);

    fill(0);
    noStroke();
    textSize(24);
    text("score: " + game_score, width/2, 20)
    textSize(12);



    // Logic to make the game character move or the background scroll.
    if(isLeft)
        {
            if(gameChar_x > width * 0.2)
            {
                gameChar_x -= 5;
            }
            else
            {
                scrollPos += 5;
            }
        }

    if(isRight)
        {
            if(gameChar_x < width * 0.8)
            {
                gameChar_x  += 5;
            }
            else
            {
                scrollPos -= 5; // negative for moving against the background
            }
        }

    // Logic to make the game character rise and fall.

    if(gameChar_y !== floorPos_y)
    {
        gameChar_y += 2
        isFalling = true;
    }
    else if(isFalling)
    {
        isFalling  = false;
    }

    if(flagpole.isReached == false)
    {
        checkFlagpole();
    }

    // Update real position of gameChar for collision detection.
    gameChar_world_x = gameChar_x - scrollPos;
}


// ---------------------
// Key control functions
// ---------------------

function keyPressed()
{
    if(keyCode == 37)
        {
            console.log("left arrow");
            isLeft = true;
        }
    else if(keyCode == 39)
        {
            console.log("right arrow");
            isRight = true;
        }

    if(keyCode == 32 && gameChar_y == floorPos_y)
        {
            console.log("jump")
            gameChar_y -=100;
        }

}

function keyReleased()
{

    if(keyCode == 37)
        {
            console.log("left arrow");
            isLeft = false;
        }
    else if(keyCode == 39)
        {
            console.log("right arrow");
            isRight = false;
        }

}


// ------------------------------
// Game character render function
// ------------------------------

// Function to draw the game character.

function drawGameChar()
{

    if(isLeft && isFalling)
        {
                // add your jumping-left code

            fill(255, 201, 169); //head
            ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 55, 30, 40);

            fill(0); //back leg
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 10, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 10);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //back arm
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 35, 10, 10);

            fill(135, 206, 235); //body
            rect(gameChar_x-10, gameChar_y - 38, 20, 15);

            fill(0) //front  leg
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 10, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 10);

            fill(0) //eye
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 11, gameChar_y - 58, 2, 10);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //front arm
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 8, gameChar_y - 30, 10, 10);
        }
    else if(isRight && isFalling)
        {
                // add your jumping-right code
            fill(255, 201, 169); //head
            ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 55, 30, 40);

            fill(0); //back leg
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 10, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 10);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //back arm
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 35, 10, 10);

            fill(135, 206, 235); //body
            rect(gameChar_x - 10, gameChar_y - 38, 20, 15);

            fill(0) //front  leg
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 10, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 10);

            fill(0) //eye
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 11, gameChar_y - 58, 2, 10);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //front arm
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 8, gameChar_y - 30, 10, 10);

        }
    else if(isLeft)
        {
                // add your walking left code
            fill(255, 201, 169); //head
            ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 45, 30, 40);

            fill(0); //back leg
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 10, gameChar_y - 7, 20, 10);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //back arm
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 25, 10, 10);

            fill(135, 206, 235); //body
            rect(gameChar_x-10, gameChar_y - 28, 20, 20);

            fill(0) //front  leg
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 10, gameChar_y - 4, 20, 10);

            fill(0) //eye
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 10);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //front arm
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 13, gameChar_y - 16, 10, 10);
        }
    else if(isRight)
        {
                // add your walking right code
            fill(255, 201, 169); //head
            ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 45, 30, 40);

            fill(0); //back leg
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 10, gameChar_y - 7, 20, 10);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //back arm
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 25, 10, 10);

            fill(135, 206, 235); //body
            rect(gameChar_x - 10, gameChar_y - 28, 20, 20);

            fill(0) //front  leg
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 10, gameChar_y - 4, 20, 10);

            fill(0) //eye
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 10);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //front arm
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 13, gameChar_y - 16, 10, 10);
        }
    else if(isFalling || isPlummeting)
        {
                // add your jumping facing forwards code
            fill(255, 201, 169);//head
            ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 55, 40, 40);

            fill(135, 206, 235); //body
            rect(gameChar_x-13, gameChar_y - 38, 26, 20);

            fill(255, 201, 169); //arms
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 13, gameChar_y - 33, 10, 10);
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 18, gameChar_y - 70, 10, 10);

            fill(0) //legs
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 10, gameChar_y - 10, 20, 10);
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 10, gameChar_y - 17, 20, 10);

            fill(0) //eyes
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 8, gameChar_y - 58, 5, 10);
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 8, gameChar_y - 58, 5, 10);
        }
    else
        {
                // add your standing front facing code
            fill(255, 201, 169);
            ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 45, 40, 40);

            fill(135, 206, 235);
            rect(gameChar_x-13, gameChar_y - 28, 26, 20);

            fill(255, 201, 169);
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 13, gameChar_y - 18, 10, 10);
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 13, gameChar_y - 18, 10, 10);

            fill(0)
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 10, gameChar_y - 5, 20, 10);
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 10, gameChar_y - 5, 20, 10);

            fill(0)
            ellipse(gameChar_x - 8, gameChar_y - 48, 5, 10);
            ellipse(gameChar_x + 8, gameChar_y - 48, 5, 10); 
            strokeWeight(0)

        }   
}

// ---------------------------
// Background render functions
// ---------------------------

// Function to draw cloud objects.
function drawClouds()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < clouds.length; i++)
        {
            fill(255,255,255);
            ellipse(clouds[i].pos_x,
                    clouds[i].pos_y, 70, 80);
            ellipse(clouds[i].pos_x + 30,
                    clouds[i].pos_y, 80, 100);
            ellipse(clouds[i].pos_x + 60, 
                    clouds[i].pos_y, 80, 100);
            ellipse(clouds[i].pos_x + 90,
                    clouds[i].pos_y, 70, 80);
        }
}
// Function to draw mountains objects.
function drawMountains()
{    
 for (var i = 0; i < mountains.length; i++)
    {   
    fill(120, 120, 120);
    triangle(mountains[i].pos_x,
             mountains[i].pos_y,
             mountains[i].pos_x + 270,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 326,
             mountains[i].pos_x + 410,
             mountains[i].pos_y);
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    triangle(mountains[i].pos_x + 310,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 247,
             mountains[i].pos_x + 267,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 326,
             mountains[i].pos_x + 270,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 266);

    triangle(mountains[i].pos_x + 280,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 266, 
             mountains[i].pos_x + 267,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 326,
             mountains[i].pos_x + 210,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 255);

    triangle(mountains[i].pos_x + 225, 
             mountains[i].pos_y - 267,
             mountains[i].pos_x + 260,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 247,
             mountains[i].pos_x + 300,
             mountains[i].pos_y - 267);
    }
}
// Function to draw trees objects.
function drawTrees()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < trees_x.length; i++)
    {
        fill(122, 31, 31); //tree
        rect(trees_x[i], treePos_y + 105, 35, 40);
        fill(34,139,34); 
        triangle(trees_x[i] + 80, 
                 treePos_y + 115,
                 trees_x[i] + 20, 
                 treePos_y + 45, 
                 trees_x[i] - 45, 
                 treePos_y + 115);
        triangle(trees_x[i] + 80, 
                 treePos_y + 75, 
                 trees_x[i] + 20, 
                 treePos_y - 5,
                 trees_x[i] - 45,
                 treePos_y + 75);
    }
}

// ---------------------------------
// Canyon render and check functions
// ---------------------------------

// Function to draw canyon objects.

function drawCanyon(t_canyon)
{
    fill(100, 155, 255);
    rect(t_canyon.pos_x, floorPos_y, t_canyon.width, 144);
}

// Function to check character is over a canyon.

function checkCanyon(t_canyon)
{
  if(gameChar_world_x > t_canyon.pos_x && gameChar_world_x < t_canyon.pos_x + 100)
               {
                    gameChar_y += 2
                    isFalling = true;
               }
}


// ----------------------------------
// Collectable items render and check functions
// ----------------------------------

// Function to draw collectable objects.

function drawCollectable(t_collectable)
{
    stroke(1);
    fill(255,215,0);
    ellipse(t_collectable.x_pos,
            t_collectable.y_pos - 20, 
            t_collectable.size, 
            t_collectable.size);

    ellipse(t_collectable.x_pos, 
            t_collectable.y_pos - 20, 
            t_collectable.size - 10, 
            t_collectable.size - 10);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text("$", t_collectable.x_pos - 3, 
              t_collectable.y_pos - 16);
}

// Function to check character has collected an item.

function checkCollectable(t_collectable)
{
   if(dist(gameChar_world_x, gameChar_y, 
      t_collectable.x_pos, t_collectable.y_pos - 20) < t_collectable.size) 
                {
                  t_collectable.isFound = true;
                    game_score += 1;
                }
}

function checkPlayerDie()
{   

    console.log(lives);
    if(gameChar_y > height)
    {
        lives = true;
        lives = lives -= 1;
    }    

    if(lives == true)
    {
        startGame;
    }
}

function startGame()
{
    gameChar_x = width/2;
    gameChar_y = floorPos_y;
    treePos_y = height/2;

    // Variable to control the background scrolling.
    scrollPos = 0;

    // Variable to store the real position of the gameChar in the game
    // world. Needed for collision detection.
    gameChar_world_x = gameChar_x - scrollPos;

    // Boolean variables to control the movement of the game character.
    isLeft = false;
    isRight = false;
    isFalling = false;
    isPlummeting = false;

    // Initialise arrays of scenery objects.

    trees_x = [25, 
               75, 
               125, 
               360, 
               410, 
               460, 
               800, 
               850, 
               900, 
               1240, 
               1290, 
               1340, 
               1680, 
               1730, 
               1780
              ];

    clouds = [
        {pos_x: 50, pos_y: 50},
        {pos_x: 300, pos_y: 70},
        {pos_x: 550, pos_y: 110},
        {pos_x: 800, pos_y: 70},
        {pos_x: 1000, pos_y: 50},
        {pos_x: 1250, pos_y: 70},
        {pos_x: 1500, pos_y: 110},
        {pos_x: 1750, pos_y: 50}
        ];

    mountains = [ 
        {pos_x: 75, pos_y: 432},
        {pos_x: 175, pos_y: 432},
        {pos_x: 775, pos_y: 432},
        {pos_x: 1675, pos_y: 432},
        {pos_x: 1975, pos_y: 432},
    ];

    collectables = [ 
        {x_pos: 566, y_pos: floorPos_y, size: 30, isFound: false},
        {x_pos: 700, y_pos: floorPos_y, size: 30, isFound: false},
        {x_pos: 1100, y_pos: floorPos_y, size: 30, isFound: false},
        {x_pos: 1900, y_pos: floorPos_y, size: 30, isFound: false}
    ];

    canyon = [
        {pos_x: 590, width: 100},
        {pos_x: 1450, width: 100}
        ];

    game_score = 0;

    flagpole = {isReached: false, x_pos: 2000}
}

function renderFlagpole()
{
    push();
    strokeWeight(5);
    stroke(255);
    line(flagpole.x_pos, floorPos_y, flagpole.x_pos, floorPos_y - 350);
    fill(255, 215, 0);
    noStroke();

    if(flagpole.isReached)
    {
        rect(flagpole.x_pos, floorPos_y - 50, 75, 50);
    }
    else
    {
        rect(flagpole.x_pos, floorPos_y - 350, 75, 50);  
    }
    pop();
}



function checkFlagpole()
{
    var d = abs(gameChar_world_x - flagpole.x_pos);

    if(d < 15)
    {
        flagpole.isReached = true;
    }
}
```

I have added the code and also below is what i was working on.

https://editor.p5js.org/conorwykes/present/zvxNtkcy

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your error is here:

```
function checkPlayerDie()
{   

    console.log(lives);
    if(gameChar_y > height)
    {
        lives = true;
        lives = lives -= 1;
    }    

    if(lives == true)
    {
        startGame;
    }
}
```

Specifically these two lines:

```
lives = true;
lives = lives -= 1;
```

I assume your intention is for `lives` to be an integer value counting the quantity of remaining lives of the character. However, you're changing the value to a boolean `true` value, essentially discarding any quantity that existed. Thus, because `true - 1` results in `0` you've immediately lost all existing lives.

I think you'd also want to change the `if` condition below to `if (lives > 0)`, if I'm understanding your logic correctly.

Also, while this isn't an error, I'd suggest altering the next line, `lives = lives -= 1`. Here you're being redundant because you're combining the [Assignment Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) with the [Substraction Assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Subtraction_assignment). You should change this to either just `lives -= 1;` or `lives = lives - 1;`.

EDIT:

I just ran your code, and also noticed that, in order for it to work correctly, you need to put the second `if` statement within the first `if` statement. This is the edit I made that results in it working correctly:

```
function checkPlayerDie()
{   
    console.log(lives);
    if(gameChar_y > height)
    {
        lives -= 1;

      if(lives > 0)
      {
          startGame();
      }
    }    
}
```